# No se ve bien el nuevo formato de Stack Snippets

Tags: bug, estado-completado, stack-snippets

Acabo de darme cuenta que el nuevo formato de los stack snippets no se ve bien, cuando se ejecuta, botones se ven encimados...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podríamos resolverlo simplemente utilizando **"Ejecutar"** y **"Copiar a nueva respuesta"**, he aquí como quedaría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que dicen?

Comment: Creo que también deberíamos considerar quitarle un poco de `padding`, actualmente tiene `20px` de cada lado lo que me parece demasiado.

Comment: Pero este cambio lo podemos hacer desde tranferix sin intervención de la gente de desarrollo

Comment: @rnd Tranquilo, la gente de desarrollo nunca duerme :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hecho. Así es como luce ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: awesome! es decir... excelente!